# font dropdown arrow not showing

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, fonts

I've got a dropdown field with dropdown arrow which is handled by WebSymbolsRegular font. I uploaded the font files to the server, set the font-face and put the font symbol I wanted as :after in the css for the dropdown. For some odd reason it isn't working, help would be appreciated as I haven't really done anything like this before.

Here's the code:

```css
.selectadmin {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #666;
  background: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-radius: 5px; 
}

.selectadmin:before {
  font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
 content: ';';
  position: absolute;
  right: 9px;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 235%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
}
.selectadmin:before {
  font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
  content: '{';
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 200%;
}
.selectadmin:after {
  font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
  content: '}';
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 120%;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
    src: url("fonts/backend/WebSymbols-Regular.eot");
    src: url("fonts/backend/WebSymbols-Regular.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
         url("fonts/backend/WebSymbols-Regular.woff") format('woff'),
         url("fonts/backend/WebSymbols-Regular.ttf") format('truetype'),
         url("fonts/backend/WebSymbols-Regular.svg#WebSymbolsRegular") format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.glyph, .menu a:before { font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular'; }
a.glyph:hover { text-decoration: none; }

/** colors **/
.glyph.white { color: #fff; }
.glyph.black { color: #000; }
.glyph.grey { color: #5c5c5c; }

/** sizes **/
.glyph.size10{ font-size: 10px !important; }
.glyph.size11{ font-size: 11px !important; }
.glyph.size12{ font-size: 12px !important; }
.glyph.size13{ font-size: 13px !important; }
.glyph.size14{ font-size: 14px !important; }
.glyph.size16{ font-size: 16px !important; }
.glyph.size18{ font-size: 18px !important; }
.glyph.size20{ font-size: 20px !important; }
.glyph.size24{ font-size: 24px !important; }
.glyph.size30{ font-size: 30px !important; }
.glyph.size36{ font-size: 36px !important; }
.glyph.size48{ font-size: 48px !important; }
.glyph.size60{ font-size: 60px !important; }
.glyph.size72{ font-size: 72px !important; }
.glyph.size90{ font-size: 90px !important; }

/** names **/
.glyph.image:before,.menu a[data-icon="image"]:before { content: "I" }
.glyph.settings:before,.menu a[data-icon="settings"]:before { content: "S" }
.glyph.cloud:before,.menu a[data-icon="cloud"]:before { content: "C" }
.glyph.archive:before,.menu a[data-icon="archive"]:before { content: "Z" }
.glyph.movie:before,.menu a[data-icon="movie"]:before { content: "M" }
.glyph.html-code:before,.menu a[data-icon="html-code"]:before { content: "H" }
.glyph.text:before,.menu a[data-icon="text"]:before { content: "T" }
.glyph.terminal:before,.menu a[data-icon="terminal"]:before { content: "_" }
.glyph.attachment:before,.menu a[data-icon="attachment"]:before { content: "A" }
.glyph.folder:before,.menu a[data-icon="folder"]:before { content: "F" }
.glyph.logout:before,.menu a[data-icon="logout"]:before { content: "X" }
.glyph.indent:before,.menu a[data-icon="indent"]:before { content: "n" }
.glyph.outdent:before,.menu a[data-icon="outdent"]:before { content: "o" }
.glyph.list:before,.menu a[data-icon="list"]:before { content: "p" }
.glyph.number-list:before,.menu a[data-icon="number-list"]:before { content: "q" }
.glyph.move:before,.menu a[data-icon="move"]:before { content: "~" }
.glyph.user:before,.menu a[data-icon="user"]:before { content: "U" }
.glyph.opened-lock:before,.menu a[data-icon="opened-lock"]:before { content: "w" }
.glyph.closed-lock:before,.menu a[data-icon="closed-lock"]:before { content: "x" }
.glyph.portrait-view:before,.menu a[data-icon="portrait-view"]:before { content: "a" }
.glyph.album-view:before,.menu a[data-icon="album-view"]:before { content: "b" }
.glyph.center:before,.menu a[data-icon="center"]:before { content: "`" }
.glyph.zoom-in:before,.menu a[data-icon="zoom-in"]:before { content: "+" }
.glyph.zoom-out:before,.menu a[data-icon="zoom-out"]:before { content: "-" }
.glyph.up:before,.menu a[data-icon="up"]:before { content: ":" }
.glyph.down:before,.menu a[data-icon="down"]:before { content: ";" }
.glyph.close:before,.menu a[data-icon="close"]:before { content: "×" }
.glyph.scale:before,.menu a[data-icon="scale"]:before { content: "&" }
.glyph.back:before,.menu a[data-icon="back"]:before { content: "(" }
.glyph.forward:before,.menu a[data-icon="forward"]:before { content: ")" }
.glyph.back-2:before,.menu a[data-icon="back-2"]:before { content: "<" }
.glyph.forward-2:before,.menu a[data-icon="forward-2"]:before { content: ">" }
.glyph.rotate:before,.menu a[data-icon="rotate"]:before { content: "*" }
.glyph.close-2:before,.menu a[data-icon="close-2"]:before { content: "'" }
.glyph.twitter:before,.menu a[data-icon="twitter"]:before { content: "t" }
.glyph.facebook:before,.menu a[data-icon="facebook"]:before { content: "f" }
.glyph.vkontakte:before,.menu a[data-icon="vkontakte"]:before { content: "v" }
.glyph.linked-in:before,.menu a[data-icon="linked-in"]:before { content: "l" }
.glyph.skype:before,.menu a[data-icon="skype"]:before { content: "s" }
.glyph.rss:before,.menu a[data-icon="rss"]:before { content: "r" }
.glyph.vimeo:before,.menu a[data-icon="vimeo"]:before { content: "m" }
.glyph.youtube:before,.menu a[data-icon="youtube"]:before { content: "y" }
.glyph.tumblr:before,.menu a[data-icon="tumblr"]:before { content: "k" }
.glyph.lettery:before,.menu a[data-icon="lettery"]:before { content: "z" }
.glyph.odnoklassniki:before,.menu a[data-icon="odnoklassniki"]:before { content: "Q" }
.glyph.rss-2:before,.menu a[data-icon="rss-2"]:before { content: "B" }
.glyph.favorite:before,.menu a[data-icon="favorite"]:before { content: "R" }
.glyph.tag:before,.menu a[data-icon="tag"]:before { content: "," }
.glyph.comment:before,.menu a[data-icon="comment"]:before { content: "c" }
.glyph.chat:before,.menu a[data-icon="chat"]:before { content: "d" }
.glyph.opened-chat:before,.menu a[data-icon="opened-chat"]:before { content: "e" }
.glyph.rating:before,.menu a[data-icon="rating"]:before { content: "u" }
.glyph.map-pin:before,.menu a[data-icon="map-pin"]:before { content: "?" }
.glyph.like:before,.menu a[data-icon="like"]:before { content: "N" }
.glyph.unlike:before,.menu a[data-icon="unlike"]:before { content: "O" }
.glyph.search:before,.menu a[data-icon="search"]:before { content: "L" }
.glyph.reblog:before,.menu a[data-icon="reblog"]:before { content: "J" }
.glyph.open-in-new-window:before,.menu a[data-icon="open-in-new-window"]:before { content: "D" }
.glyph.clock:before,.menu a[data-icon="clock"]:before { content: "P" }
.glyph.link:before,.menu a[data-icon="link"]:before { content: "K" }
.glyph.mail:before,.menu a[data-icon="mail"]:before { content: "@" }
.glyph.sort:before,.menu a[data-icon="sort"]:before { content: "{" }
.glyph.sort-2:before,.menu a[data-icon="sort-2"]:before { content: "}" }
.glyph.unfold:before,.menu a[data-icon="unfold"]:before { content: "[" }
.glyph.fold:before,.menu a[data-icon="fold"]:before { content: "]" }
.glyph.icon:before,.menu a[data-icon="icon"]:before { content: "¹" }
.glyph.list-2:before,.menu a[data-icon="list-2"]:before { content: "²" }
.glyph.list-with-icons:before,.menu a[data-icon="list-with-icons"]:before { content: "³" }
.glyph.reply:before,.menu a[data-icon="reply"]:before { content: "h" }
.glyph.reply-all:before,.menu a[data-icon="reply-all"]:before { content: "i" }
.glyph.forward-3:before,.menu a[data-icon="forward-3"]:before { content: "j" }
.glyph.fullscreen:before,.menu a[data-icon="fullscreen"]:before { content: "%" }
.glyph.done:before,.menu a[data-icon="done"]:before { content: "." }
.glyph.approved:before,.menu a[data-icon="approved"]:before { content: "/" }
.glyph.attention:before,.menu a[data-icon="attention"]:before { content: "W" }
.glyph.synchronize:before,.menu a[data-icon="synchronize"]:before { content: "V" }
```

Answer (score 0):

The @font-face rule should be added to the stylesheet before any styles.

Try changing .selectadmin position to relative.

Comment: Oh, thanks for letting me know! Moved it to the top of the stylesheet along with other fonts used. Still isn't showing up. The font files are valid since they show up fine in a program like Photoshop.

Comment: Why do you have 2 .selectadmin:before rules?

Comment: Unfortunately no change.

Comment: Do you have this running online, so I can see and inspect? @BK1

Comment: I can put it online, I've at least found the source of my problems. It's nothing to do with the CSS it's how I'm trying to do make it show. I'm trying to do <select class ="selectadmin"><option stuff here></option></select> but it clearly doesn't like that. I tried wrapping it in a div class of selectadmin but it didn't make the dropdown arrow show.

Comment: @BK1 Can you please send all code involved and maybe an image of what you wanna do? I want so much to help you

Comment: There's no way to private message you on this site unfortunately. I'm trying to get https://i.imgur.com/r2ULNkv.png these two font arrow icons onto this https://i.imgur.com/VYsuEKP.png so it looks like this - https://i.imgur.com/jbMVBwp.png